# 2021 Corolla LE transmission issue; shifter caught between "B" and "D"

Tags: toyota, transmission, corolla, shifting, shifter

First time posting!  I'll get to it.

First off, i have a 2021 corolla LE.

So the other day I'm driving, and noticed my car wasn't behaving like normal.  I looked down at the shifter and it is stuck between the D symbol and B symbol.  I can't recall if I popped it back into D while coming to a stop at a light or if I waited until the car was stopped,  but I did pop it back into D withing seconds of me noticing it.  Also, no funny noises, no jerks, just a lack of response on the throttle I think it was.  When I tried to get moving the car felt extremely underpowered and continued this even as I gave it gas.  It barely moved.  I shifted (smoothly) into park and turned the car off, and turned it back on.  Same problem.  So I REALLY gave it some gas this time and it moved just enough to pull into a parking space.  I put it into park again and let it sit for a while, then started it back up and it felt more normal.

Anyways, that was like 3 days ago.  Since then.....

The car feels like it has a 1st, sometimes 2nd, and a 4th gear.  It almost seems to skip 3rd.  When it slows down, by braking or me just taking my food off the gas, it feels like when you downshift in a manual to slow down the car through the gears but with this it is much MUCH less pronounced.  There are no wierd noises, no wierd vibrations (new ones) I drive for uber so I drive all day and have had no problems other than he ones described.  Also, last night, i was going like 55 (not for the first time since) and the car sounded like it was REALLY trying to slow itself down through the gears

So, to reiterate:

- car doesn't shift like normal but drives fine
- car seems to skip 3rd gear, maybe something else but def a gear in the middle of the set
- no funny noises or sensations
- car drives find at speeds up to around 55, 60 is most I've pushed it but still performed okay
- I can floor it in "D" or "B" and the power is there like normal, up to like 35ish (don't want a ticket).

Please let me know what it is you guys think.  Car has 39k miles on it if that helps.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: A 2021 vehicle with 39k miles should still be under warranty?

Comment: @WeatherVane Most non-luxury cars in the US have a bumper-to-bumper warranty that expires after 36k miles, including Toyota.

Comment: @user71659 in UK 3 years or 60k miles is common, but not less than the statutory one year.